# Videocall from Web SDK to iOS SDK

Tags: agora.io

WebSDK doesn't receive published stream from iOS SDK

Currenty, I've completed WebSDK based videocall. User1 joins to the chatX and publishes his stream. User2 receives this stream via "stream-added" event in the chatX and successfully subscribes for it.
But "stream-added" event doesn't fire when user1 joins to videochat from iOS App.

```
        client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {
            var stream = evt.stream;
            console.log("New stream added: " + stream.getId());
            console.log("Subscribe ", stream);
            client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
                console.log("Subscribe stream failed", err);
            });
        });

        client.on('stream-subscribed', function (evt) {
            var stream = evt.stream;
            console.log("Subscribe remote stream successfully: " + stream.getId());
            if ($('#videochat-remoteVideo #agora_remote'+stream.getId()).length === 0) {
                $('#videochat-remoteVideo').append('<div id="agora_remote'+stream.getId()+'"></div>');
            }
            remoteBigLocalSmall();
            stream.play('agora_remote' + stream.getId());
        });
```

iOS app reveives the stream published from Web, whereas Web client doesn't receives the stream from iOS client.

What can be wrong with my implementation? How to receive stream from iOS client?

UPD:
Join chat code:

```
user_id = '111';
client.join(channel_key, videochat_id, user_id, function(uid) {
...
```

I've changed user_id type from string to int and now it works. I can't understand why, because documentation allows string uid:

> join(tokenOrKey: string | null, channel: string, uid: number | string
>   | null, onSuccess?: function, onFailure?: function): void

Comment: which version of the Agora.io Web SDK are you using?

Comment: @Hermes, latest, 2.8

Comment: Have you made sure to enable WebInteroperabilityMode on iOS? https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/enableWebSdkInteroperability:

Comment: iOS developer said that this option disabled

Comment: the WebInteroperabilityMode needs to be set to enabled.

Comment: the lack of string support for uid in the join method sounds like a bug. I will file a ticket.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help

Comment: When you set the string ID in iOS are you first registering the string or are you trying to use it in iOS the way you are passing it in JS? In iOS you have to first call `registerLocalUserAccount ` before you can call `joinChannelByUserAccount` ... what method are you using to join the channel?

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/string_ios?platform=iOS

Comment: In iOS used joinChannelByToken method with token : nil, info : nil, uid : 0 and channelId : someID;

Comment: In iOS to use String `id` you need to use `registerLocalUserAccount` and use `joinChannelByUserAccount` instead of joining by token.

Comment: moved my response to an answer to provide the code snippet that you need to use

Comment: @Hermes, thank you for your participation. I think, it would be great if these features of SDKs interaction will be documented for the future generations:)

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I will file some tickets with the Documentation team to get these snippets added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is related to your use of the wrong API Method. You are using `joinChannelByToken` which only works with Integer values when you should be using `joinChannel(byUserAccount: ...)` because that takes a String `uid` as a parameter.

```
let myStringId = "someStringId"
agoraKit.joinChannel(byUserAccount: myStringId, token: nil, channelId: "demoChannel1") { (sid, uid, elapsed) in
    // Did join channel "demoChannel1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing client.join method parameter uid from string to integer resolved the issue